# dojo dijit.Dialog undimming

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am still having problems "undimming" a dojo dijit dialog.  I am matching the calls but many times I still have portions of the page dimmed.  I can scroll the windows and the undimmed areas are accessible.  How can I forceably undim or the DOM equivalent the entire page?  Secondarily is there a way call digit.Dialog to "dim" the entire page not just the part in the current viewport?

Comment: Dimmer for dijit/Dialog should work out of the box and dimming all your page, if only a portion of page is dimmed, could be a problem in your application code. Try to reproduce the error with a minimum code and post it on SO and we can have a look a it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should work out the box with most layouts. The `<div class="dijitDialogUnderlay _underlay" ...` is the 'dim' which covers the container, in which the dialog is placed.

Try doing `dijit.byId('##YOURID##').placeAt('body');` to 'cover' the outmost container.

I made a simple test in below fiddle, with latest dojo 1.1x, the underlay even has an eventlistener on `resize`, which then streches the div to cover less/more.

If placing in `body` doesnt do the trick, make sure the DOM containing your widget, has `position` set before rendering the Dialog. This will trigger position / sizing more accurate

http://jsfiddle.net/mzh2su2c/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dojox.layout.FloatingPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/layout/FloatingPane.html) instead, which by design has not dimmer.

Nethertheless, if you really want to use a `dijit/Dialog` you could hack it using this CSS solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/mzh2su2c/6/

```
.dijitDialogUnderlay {
  pointer-events: none; /* avoid dimmer to become the target of mouse events*/
  display: none; /* hide the dimmer*/
}
```